# Linux - Execution of instructions on stack

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, stack

I have a tool, which I compile using the Makefiles. It is a very big tool and has many Makefiles. It generates a shared library (.so file) after compilation. When I checked with `execstack -q <file.so>`, it shows that the execution of instructions on stack is required for this library.

To enable stack execution for any program we can compile it by giving the option `-z execstack` to `gcc`. Now, I am explicitly not providing this option anywhere, but still for the generated shared library this flag gets enabled.

I am linking some libraries for which this flag is enabled. Is that the reason for this flag being enabled for the shared library ?

If No, what else can be the reason ?

Comment: Sounds suspicious to me..........

Comment: It really is !! :)

Comment: Linker directives can be inside the binary itself. You can look a the section `.drectve`

Comment: I could not find any section called `.drectve`. I checked the sections by  the `readelf -S` command . . It lists all the sections of the binary. Even the `.note.GNU_STACK` section was not there. But I have some other object files. And when I run this `readelf -S` command on the object files, it shows the `.note.GNU_STACK` section. What I am trying to figure out over here is that from where, the stack execution flag is getting enabled ?